# Connecting Values From Separate Databases

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 separate databases for different stores. There are products that will be on both databases that need the quantity connected. I thought maybe a SQL Trigger would work every time someone buys from one it updates the other, but the join query runs VERY slow.

The first database was done by a previous developer and has about 65,000 products in it. It is very badly done and I am attempting to move the new store using a different setup. Any suggestions or if you can think of a solution would be greatly appreciated. I have been racking my brain on this one.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use [MySQL Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-howto.html) to replicate data from the first database to the second. You would then have visibility of the product data from both databases on the second database allowing you to query both data sets using a single query i.e. a query running on just the second database.

Comment: Would I be able to replicate with column names as aliases? The databases are set up different from each other.